# Why is this out of bound?

Tags: java

My hand array size is 5. I have no idea why it's giving me an out of bounds array error. Any idea?

```
public void sortHandCard()
    {
        for(int i = 0; i <= hand.length; i++)
        {
            for(int j = i + 1; j <= hand.length; j++)
            {
                if(hand[i].getNumber() > hand[j].getNumber())
                {
                    Card c = hand[i];
                    hand[i] = hand[j];
                    hand[j] = c;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Post the exact error output would be great help for others to help you.

Answer (score 3):

Change `<=` to just `<`.  The last index is one less than the length of the array since the indexing starts at 0.